# How do I override compiled classes?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I cam trying to apply override styles to a compiled class name. my compiled code is like...

`<div class="MuiListItemText-root-262" >`

I want to be able to target that specific item like this

`const styles = () => { MultiListItemText-root-262: { color: red; } }`

in vanilla CSS I could just do `.MultiListItemText-root-262: { color: red; }`

How can I do the equivalent in JSS?

Comment: You can do it by define a style object for your MuiListItemText. For example const muiListStyle = { color: 'red' }, then you can use it inline <div style={muiListStyle} class="MuiListItemText-root-262" >

Comment: Or you can create a css file and import it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it this way.
The classname "MuiListItemText-root-262" is dynamic, and the id "262" is not reliable and may change.

Please look at the official documentation of Material UI for using JSS overrides : https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/

There are several techniques available depending on the level of variation your want to achieve.

For a typical "one time" override, see the first sample code which uses the withStyles HOC

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

// We can inject some CSS into the DOM.
const styles = {
  button: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    borderRadius: 3,
    border: 0,
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
  },
};

function ClassNames(props) {
  return (
    <Button className={props.classes.button}>
      {props.children ? props.children : 'class names'}
    </Button>
  );
}

ClassNames.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ClassNames);
```