# Material UI : Form styling

Tags: material-ui, redux-form

I'm looking for a solution to edit the style of my material ui form.
I would like to change the background and the border.

I try to change directly in CSS :

```
input { background:#999; }
```

But it change the background of all the div (https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/showImage?img_id=3537926)

I'm using Redux Form with Material UI : https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/material-ui/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override compiled classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51541248/how-do-i-override-compiled-classes)

Answer (score 0):

The material-ui way - in your jsx file with the form, you can define a theme which includes classNames

```
import classNames from "classnames";

....

const styles = theme => ({
  form_input: {
    background: "#999"
  },
....
```

Then, in your form or enclosed div tag, include something like...

```
className={classes.form_input}
```